power BI DAX query measure by rowwise
my Power Bi table contains measure  column called  order failure % and date column. i want measure column data by date wise using dax query. currently it is giving summarized values. how to get measure column row wise?

why was a power bi question tagged as pyspark?

Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
